# Woocommerce: How to remove "add to cart" when hovering over product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like some help removing the "Add to cart" text appearing over the product price on the product page of my WordPress website. (translated to "In winkelmand" on my page)

I have been looking all over, the options I found did not work and I am out of ideas.

Here is a screenshot of what is happening: https://snipboard.io/JrgcO2.jpg

URL: https://www.stormrotswallart.nl/winkel/

The yellow text appears when you hover over a product. It also appears on mobile when you select the product before it loads the product page.

Would someone please tell me how to disable this text from appearing? I have tried CSS (display: none) but that just makes the price disappear when you hover over the product.

Thanks in advance, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Nor the image link nor the website link work for me at the moment.

Comment: Is the URL not working? It is definately online, we can open it on our phones as well. Are you sure you can't use it? Also the link to the screenshot is still online @PetarVasilev

Comment: It works now. It looks like intentional behaviour. Check if it is doing the same thing on the theme's website.

Comment: You're right I think @PetarVasilev. It is intentional behaviour from the selected theme. I would just like the remove it :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @PetarVasilev for helping me in the right direction.I changed and added a few things, it's working like a charm now.

Eventually, what we did was:

- Move the "Add to cart" text and make it opaque (opacity: 0)
- Make the Price text not-opague (opacity: 1)
- Make the pointer stay default so it doesnt look as clickable
- Make the text tiny so people (almost) can't accidentally hover over it or click it
- Remove the margin below so there isn't a large empty area between each product
  (- Remove the margin also for small screens, it was set independantly)

CSS now looks as follows:

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover .price, .theme-block.shop .product:hover .price {
   opacity: 1 !important;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button.add_to_cart_button, .woocommerce ul.products li.product .button.product_type_simple {
   opacity: 0 !important;
   position: static !important;
   cursor: default;
   font-size: 0px;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important
   }
}
```

Thank you again @PetarVasilev for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover .price, .theme-block.shop .product:hover .price {
   opacity: 1 !important;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button.add_to_cart_button, .woocommerce ul.products li.product .button.product_type_simple {
   opacity: 1 !important;
   position: static !important;
}
```